# Giving velocity to an object based on rotation

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I'm using Cocos-Creator, currently there is no physics implemented so I kinda want to create my own. Here I try to move an object based on its rotation:

```
    properties: {

       speed: 200,
},

update: function (dt) {
    this.node.x += Math.cos(this.node.rotation) * this.speed;
    this.node.y += Math.sin(this.node.rotation) * this.speed;
},
```

But the problem is that the object is not behaving as intended to, it's moving in random directions.

Update:
The code now is:

```
update: function (dt) {
        var vX = Math.cos(this.node.rotation * Math.PI / 180) * this.speed;
        var vY = Math.sin(this.node.rotation * Math.PI / 180) * this.speed;
        this.node.x += vX * dt;
        this.node.y += vY * dt;
    },
```

Still the same problem.

Comment: Is `this.node.rotation` expressed in degrees or radians? Where do you use `dt` in your update function?

Comment: Documentation doesn't show, but it most probably  degrees.

Comment: Well, Math.cos needs radians...

Comment: No difference whether it's degrees or radians, still the same weird behaviour.

Comment: Does there need to be an adjustment for when the sine and cosine go negative.(assuming you are moving through the full 360 deg)  What about when they approach zero.  Will the Negative or zero values cause an odd effect.   Also can you shortcut this with a 90 degree offset since the only difference is the cos and sinne function,

Comment: Bob, he correctly converted from degrees to radians.

Comment: I am not sure to understand the movement you want to implement. Is it like a wheel rotation depicted as a moving forward wheel ?